# Adding a checkbox symbol using OOo API VB.NET and UNO

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, openoffice.org, uno

I've been searching for a solution for this for quite some time now but with no luck.

I have a PDF that I am generating using VB.NET, the OpenOffice API and UNO. I am generating a text document and I need to be able to insert a checkbox in code.

One possible solution is to change the font to Wingdings and just type 'o' but that solution is neither elegant nor very easy to implement given my environment (using company created code for text document creation and manipulation, have a Write command that will write to the document (strings)).

If it's possible to just add the checkbox to a string of text then that would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use an image of a checkbox (one checked and the other unchecked) and then inject that into your PDF, like this:

Caveat - I have worked with `iTextSharp` so the following code is relevant to `iTextSharp`, but the concept should translate to whatever PDF generating library/framework you are using

Method #1 - Put checkbox image into table cell

```
Dim imgCheckBoxChecked As Image = Image.GetInstance(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("checkbox_checked.gif"))
Dim imgCheckBoxUnChecked As Image = Image.GetInstance(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("checkbox_unchecked.gif"))

Dim table As Table
Dim cell As Cell

cell = New Cell(New Paragraph("", font))

'' Add checked or unchecked here
cell.AddElement(imgCheckBoxChecked)
cell.AddElement(imgCheckBoxUnChecked)
table.AddCell(cell)
```

Method #2 - Put checkbox image into the document

```
'' Add checked or unchecked here
pdfDoc.Add(imgCheckBoxChecked)
pdfDoc.Add(imgCheckBoxUnChecked)
```

Note: You will obviously need to find or create the `.gif` images for checked and unchecked.

Comment: I will play around with this. Unfortunately I'm restricted to the OpenOffice API. Thank you I'll report back if I got to work using this method.

Comment: Is there a way of doing it by just modifying the properties set?

Comment: @NewGuy - sorry I am not familiar with the OpenOffice API enough to answer that. :-(